# Core Data Reading Data in Thread that's added in the Main Thread

Tags: multithreading, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nspersistentdocument

I have a Mac document-based app, using NSPersistentDocument for the document model.

When new document is created, the app adds some default data (several sport objects and user data) to the document in the initiWithType method.

```
- (id)initWithType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError {
self = [super initWithType:typeName error:outError];

NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];

[[SportManagement sharedManager] addDefaultSports:managedObjectContext];
[[UserManagement sharedManager] addDefaultUser:managedObjectContext];

[managedObjectContext processPendingChanges];

return self;
```

}

The app has an import function that imports data from some hardware, which runs in a thread, which I set up as follows (managedObjectContext is that of the NSPersistentDocument):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^ {

    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSConfinementConcurrencyType];
    [moc setPersistentStoreCoordinator:[managedObjectContext persistentStoreCoordinator]];
```

Data is imported from the hardware into a number of NSManagedDataObject items. Each ManagedObject has a 'Sport' field, which needs to be populated with one of the sport objects created when the document was created.

However, none of the sport objects that were added in the `- (id)initWithType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError` exist in the new ManagedObjectContext in the thread (moc).

If I run the app, create a new document, then let the app sit idle for a minute-or-so, then try the import, then the Sport objects DO exist in the thread Managed Object Context.

How do I sync the new ManagedObjectContext in the thread with the main one from the NSPersistantDocument?

I've tried: `[managedObjectContext processPendingChanges];` and `[managedObjectContext setStalenessInterval];`, but neither seem the solve this problem.

Interestingly, this doesn't appear to happen in Mac OS X 10.8, only in 10.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup your "main" MOC to receive `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` notifications, and merge the changes when the background MOC saves with `-mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:`.

**EDIT**

OK, it looks like you have made your changes in the MOC, but it is just a scratchpad.  Until the data is actually saved to the persistent store, the persistent store does not know about the new data changes.

Thus, when you create your other MOC and connect it to the PSC, it does not know about those changes.

You can tell when autosave kicks in, because "after a while" it works.

I would try a manual save of the document after you create the initial content.

Comment: I've already got that in the app, but that's for getting the data added in the thread back into the main thread. What I'm trying to do is to get data that's been already added to the document ManagedObjectContext in main thread to show up in the new ManagedObjectContext in the new thread.

Comment: Then I'm confused, because now, when I read your question and the comment together, I can't even picture the scenario you describe.  Namely, what do you mean by the last sentence in the comment?  Can you elaborate (and possibly with actual code that causes the problem)?

Comment: I"ve edited the original - hopefully it's a bit clearer now - thanks for your help.

Comment: Ah, right - that's a lot clearer now. So I need for force an autosave of my document before importing. Thanks for you help.